# How can I return a session variable and clear it straight after its rendered on the next refresh?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have a function which displays current admin log in information which also displays feedback messages contained in a session variable.

I had it setup so the session variable would be set to null straight after it was displayed. However in the implementation I have the function displaying the variable displays it like so:

```
function loginInfo()
{
    $code .= 'You are logged in as bob.';
    $code .= 'msg:'.$_SESSION['msg'];

    $_SESSION['msg'] = null;

    return $code;
}

function breadCrumbs($section = '')
{
    $html .= $this->loginInfo();
    $html .= '<h1><a href="/admin">Dashboard</a> &gt; '.$section.'</h1>';

    return $html;
}

function dashboard()
{
    $html .= $this->breadCrumbs('');
    $html .= '<ul>';
    $html .= etc.. 
}

-----------

$_SESSION['msg'] = 'message here';
header(Redirect "/admin");
exit();
```

then the dashboard function is called on the new page.

```
echo $admin->dashboard();
```

The above always returns null, I'm assuming its because its changed to null in the function before the $code is displayed from the return?

How can I get around this?

Comment: You code is per se correct. The problem must lie somewhere else. (PHP has no lazy evaluation. It will first construct $code with the old value of the session variable and will only then set it to null. So no problem there.)

Comment: well it doesn't work, If I remove the code to set the variable to null it works. I'll include the rest of the class perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your code is pretty fine.

You must search in another places.

Search for 2 occurences  of `loginInfo();` in your code and you'll get it

Comment: Its not declared twice.. I dont think, posted the rest of the code. All still looks ok?

Comment: @Ezra: not declared, but called

Comment: well as far as I can tell the loginInfo() is called once before the session variable is set and once after the header redirect. :P soo annoying!